# Simple AngularJS and ui.router example not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use `ui.router` in a very simple example but cannot figure out why it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="test">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> ngTest </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a ui-sref="pages.home">Home</a>
        <div ui-view></div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script>
            var $app = angular.module('test', ['ui.router']);
            $app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
                $stateProvider.state('pages', {
                    url: '/pages',
                    abstract: true
                });
                $stateProvider.state('pages.home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    template: '<h1> Hello </h1><p> {{ message }} </p>',
                    controller: function($scope){
                        $scope.message = 'Hey, It works !';
                    }
                });
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the "Home" link is clicked, the URL is changed but the view is not shown !

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Try changing `url: '/pages',` to `url: '#/pages',`

Comment: ..and console layout iis?)

Comment: @Lal : Why does it need to be `#/pages`? Can you explain bit more?

Comment: try to add template with 'ui-view' directive to parent state(pages).

Comment: just give a try and tell me if its working or not.

Comment: @DmitryLobov : You're right, a template was needed in the parent state. Thanks

Comment: @Lai : Adding "#" to the url doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly modify your structure. If you are to use route like

```
$stateProvider.state('pages.home', {
```

then you would need to specify ui-view specifically inside that template for the child to be rendered. So it should be something like:

```
$stateProvider.state('pages', {
    url: '/pages',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view></div>' //pages.home template will be nested into this template.
});

$stateProvider.state('pages.home', {
    url: '/home',
    template: '<h1> Hello </h1><p> {{ message }} </p>',
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.message = 'Hey, It works !';
    }
});
```

Try it out. Cheers.

To know more, go through : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Comment: Yes the template was missing, Thanks

Comment: @webNeat: Yes the trick being, the parent template need to contain another `ui-view` which will nest the child templates. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

just change from `url` to `templateURL`. and be sure you specifying the exact location of your html.

Cheers.

Comment: I am using `ng-app` in the `html` tag

Comment: so, try to change your url to templateUrl .. and then be sure that you are specifying the exact location of your html.

Comment: The template is fine, the problem was that template is missing in the parent state

Comment: ahh okay bro ,, you are rigth. glad that you solve it.